# Can I scrape public LinkedIn posts for a database without authentication?

Tags: database, linkedin-api

Is there a way to create a database of LinkedIn posts? These posts would include public posts by other users, so authentication is out of the question.

I want to create a database of top performing LinkedIn posts. Any way I can do that?

I checked Kaggle and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com). But most posts are incomplete.
I've also gone through the LinkedIn API docs and was unable to find any API which would return posts of a user just based on the URN/ID of the user. Every API requires the authentication token of the user.